# How to verify the multiple added product is same in shopping cart using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to verify the multiple added product in the shopping cart is same as the selected product from product page. Like I have shown in the image
I am using http://organicgarden.co.in

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGc5Q.png)

I have tried the following to get the product name from the Shopping cart.But the element.size() count is coming wrong .everytime it comes 2 even if there are suppose 5 product present in the shopping cart

```
    public class VerifyShoppingCart {

   public static void sleep(final long millis) {
        System.out.println((String.format("sleeping %d ms", millis)));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Enter Url
    driver.get("http://www.organicgarden.co.in");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    sleep(20000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel2']/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/a[1]")).click();
    sleep(20000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel3']/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/a[1]")).click();
    sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel3']/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/a[1]")).click();
    sleep(20000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cartP")).click();
    sleep(1000);

    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rollbar-content"));

    System.out.println("element.size : "+element.size());
    for(WebElement ele:element)
    {

        System.out.println( "............"+ele.getText());


    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your tests all set up but need to verify that those items exist in the shopping cart. You can try to search for those items from the cart with XPATH for example:

```
.//*[text()="Potato 5 KG (Bulk)"]
```

Or get all the cart elements with your selenium driver and verify their content by looking at their innerHTML etc.

Edit: Looking at the site, it seems your selector is not correct. Try this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".simpleCart_items label"));
```

Comment: yes i got only product name and Item code.But i also want the price of the product with them

Comment: Hi Piittis, can you reply , how to get price of the product as I am getting product name and Item code from driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".simpleCart_items label"));

Comment: Do i need too again define List<WebElement> element2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".simpleCart_items h5"));  .Or i will do it in already defined  List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".simpleCart_items label , h5")); Please clear my doubt.It would be very helpful

Comment: Probably many ways to achieve what you want to do. I suggest you try your selectors with a browser to work out how to get the elements you need. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/search-dom-tree-by-css-selector

Comment: Yes,To get the price of the product I did like this driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".simpleCart_items label , .simpleCart_items h5"));

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG or Junit then you can go for assertions

Refer below link for TestNG:-

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/assertions-in-testng

http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/03/assertassertequals-testng-with-selenium.html

Refer below link for JUnit:-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_using_assertion.htm

If you are not using any of that then you need to use conditions like

```
if(string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2))
{
    System.out.println("Equal");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)